# How do I get user input in the Self language?

Tags: programming-languages, user-input, smalltalk, selflanguage

I'm experimenting with the [Self language](http://selflanguage.org/) and I just past the point of easy canned stuff.  I want to prompt the user for a number, or perhaps provide a form for several numbers.  Is there an equivalent to a scripting language's stdin-input, or a simple dialog, or do I have to grok Mophic and build it from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Morphic is available in Squeak too.

Find any Morph in which Text can be entered (doesnt matter if single/multi-lined), middle-click it, clone it and create a reference to it. Then, for that object implement  #keyUp:evt. The message that invokes this method is sent when the user releases a key on his keyboard *when this Morph has the keyboard-focus*. In the method you can get the text contained in the Morph and parse it.